# Matrix initialization - how to avoid overlapping?

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran77, fortran-common-block

I have a 21x21 matrix which, in majority, holds ones. Certain elements need to be initialized by discrete numbers. The existing solution is a two step initialization: first set all elements to 1 then reassign selected elements to discrete numbers.

This is implemented in a legacy FORTRAN77 code, see below, and it compiles well with *gfortran-4.9* (even without warning).

However, I need to compile it on an older server running *gfortran-4.4*. This fails, together with alternative tools like *f2c* or the *g95* compiler, due to "overlapping initialization".

Now, how can I recode the problem that it avoids this overlap in the special BLOCK DATA program unit? I also think it is not recommended albeit possible with the Intel Fortran Compiler because the order of initialization cannot be guaranteed.

```
      SUBROUTINE TEST 
      REAL*8 MAT(21,21)
      COMMON /PARAMETERS/ MAT
      END

      BLOCK DATA 
      REAL*8 MAT(21,21)
      COMMON /PARAMETERS/ MAT
      DATA MAT/441*1/
      DATA (MAT(1,J),J=2,19)/
     &     0.971440D0, 0.940444D0, 1, 0.994435D0, 0.708218D0,
     &     0.931484D0, 1.170520D0, 0.990124D0, 1, 1.019530D0,
     &     0.989844D0, 1.002350D0, 0.999248D0, 1.107274D0, 0.880880D0,
     &     0.880973D0, 0.881047D0, 0.881141D0/
      DATA (MAT(2,J),J=3,14)/
     &     1.022740D0, 0.970120D0, 0.945939D0, 0.744954D0, 0.902271D0,
     &     1.084320D0, 1.005710D0, 1.021000D0, 0.944914D0, 0.973384D0,
     &     0.959340D0, 0.945520D0/
      DATA (MAT(3,J),J=4,19)/
     &     0.925053D0, 0.940237D0, 0.849408D0, 0.955052D0, 1.281790D0,
     &     1.5D0, 1, 0.904849D0, 0.897342D0, 0.724255D0,
     &     0.859744D0, 0.855134D0, 0.831229D0, 0.808310D0, 0.784323D0,
     &     0.745171D0/
      DATA (MAT(4,J),J=5,14)/1.022540D0, 0.493148D0, 0.944871D0,
     &     1.144440D0, 3*1, 1.013040D0, 1, 1.00532D0/
      DATA (MAT(5,J),J=8,12)/1.034787D0, 3*1, 1.0049D0/
      DATA (MAT(7,J),J=15,19)/1.008492D0, 1.010124D0, 1.011501D0,
     &     1.012821D0, 1.014089D0/
      DATA (MAT(8,J),J=9,12)/1.1D0, 1, 1.3D0, 1.3D0/
      END
```

Comment: Yes, you will need to initialize each element of `mat` (at most) once.  But it seems to me that the obvious answer of mixing in the elements which should be `1` with the other elements given in the subsequent `data` statements may not be what you are after.  Is that true?

Comment: just do the `DATA MAT/441*1/` in block data, then move everything else to an initializer subroutine with executable assignments.

Comment: If I were doing that, though @agentp, I wouldn't bother with the `block data` in the first place.  [Still a solution, that said.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If "overlapping initialization" is not allowed, a simple approach may be just to insert `n*1` before and after the specific data and fill the remaining part with 1 also, for example,

```
      BLOCK DATA 
      REAL*8 MAT(21,21)
      COMMON /PARAMETERS/ MAT
      DATA MAT(1,:) / 1,
     &     0.971440D0, 0.940444D0, 1, 0.994435D0, 0.708218D0,
     &     0.931484D0, 1.170520D0, 0.990124D0, 1, 1.019530D0,
     &     0.989844D0, 1.002350D0, 0.999248D0, 1.107274D0, 0.880880D0,
     &     0.880973D0, 0.881047D0, 0.881141D0, 2*1 /
      DATA MAT(2,:) / 2*1,
     &     1.022740D0, 0.970120D0, 0.945939D0, 0.744954D0, 0.902271D0,
     &     1.084320D0, 1.005710D0, 1.021000D0, 0.944914D0, 0.973384D0,
     &     0.959340D0, 0.945520D0, 7*1 /
      DATA MAT(3,:) / 3*1,
     &     0.925053D0, 0.940237D0, 0.849408D0, 0.955052D0, 1.281790D0,
     &     1.5D0, 1, 0.904849D0, 0.897342D0, 0.724255D0,
     &     0.859744D0, 0.855134D0, 0.831229D0, 0.808310D0, 0.784323D0,
     &     0.745171D0, 2*1 /
      DATA MAT(4,:) / 4*1,
     &     1.022540D0, 0.493148D0, 0.944871D0,
     &     1.144440D0, 3*1, 1.013040D0, 1, 1.00532D0, 7*1 /
      DATA MAT(5,:) / 7*1, 1.034787D0, 3*1, 1.0049D0, 9*1 /
      DATA MAT(6,:) / 21*1 /
      DATA MAT(7,:) / 14*1,
     &     1.008492D0, 1.010124D0, 1.011501D0,
     &     1.012821D0, 1.014089D0, 2*1 /
      DATA MAT(8,:) / 8*1, 1.1D0, 1, 1.3D0, 1.3D0, 9*1 /
      DATA MAT(9:21,:) / 273*1 /
      END
```

As suggested in the comments, another approach is to replace all the DATA statements by array assignments, for example,

```
      SUBROUTINE init_data
      IMPLICIT NONE
      REAL*8 MAT(21,21), ONE
      COMMON /PARAMETERS/ MAT
      PARAMETER ( ONE = 1.0D0 )
      INTEGER i

      MAT(:,:) = ONE

      MAT(1, 2:19) = [
     &     0.971440D0, 0.940444D0, ONE,        0.994435D0, 0.708218D0,
     &     0.931484D0, 1.170520D0, 0.990124D0, ONE,        1.019530D0,
     &     0.989844D0, 1.002350D0, 0.999248D0, 1.107274D0, 0.880880D0,
     &     0.880973D0, 0.881047D0, 0.881141D0 ]
      MAT(2, 3:14) = [
     &     1.022740D0, 0.970120D0, 0.945939D0, 0.744954D0, 0.902271D0,
     &     1.084320D0, 1.005710D0, 1.021000D0, 0.944914D0, 0.973384D0,
     &     0.959340D0, 0.945520D0 ]
      MAT(3, 4:19) = [
     &     0.925053D0, 0.940237D0, 0.849408D0, 0.955052D0, 1.281790D0,
     &     1.5D0,      ONE,        0.904849D0, 0.897342D0, 0.724255D0,
     &     0.859744D0, 0.855134D0, 0.831229D0, 0.808310D0, 0.784323D0,
     &     0.745171D0 ]
      MAT(4, 5:14) = [ 1.022540D0, 0.493148D0, 0.944871D0,
     &     1.144440D0, (ONE,i=1,3), 1.013040D0, ONE, 1.00532D0 ]
      MAT(5, 8:12) = [ 1.034787D0, (ONE,i=1,3), 1.0049D0 ]
      MAT(7, 15:19) = [ 1.008492D0, 1.010124D0, 1.011501D0,
     &                  1.012821D0, 1.014089D0 ]
      MAT(8, 9:12) = [ 1.1D0, ONE, 1.3D0, 1.3D0 ]
      END
```

which seems somewhat more neat to me. Though I have confirmed that this code works for gfortran 4.4.7, it may be necessary to use `(/.../)` instead of `[...]` for more old compilers, such that `(/ 1.0d0, 2.0d0, ... /)`. Please also note that in the second approach we need to call `init_data` at some point of the program, in contrast to `BLOCK DATA` where the data are automatically initialized upon execution of the program.

Comment: I agree with your sentiments, but may I suggest that you make this answer as F77-y as possible?  That is, fixed-form source, non-array syntax, no `[`, `::`, etc.,  That's just to make the changes as small as possible, whether or not there's truly an F77 compiiler being used.  [Yes, `real*8` isn't F77 either...]

Comment: Hi, @francescalus  then I will change the second one into a fixed format. But is it necessary also replace `[` to `(/`? Because the OP says he compiles with gfort-4.4, this `[` seems no problem (I tested with gfortran4.4.7).

Comment: Hmm, is it possible to rewrite this compactly without using structure constructors...? If I try to strictly follow Fortran77 and write one assignment per element, the code becomes extremely lengthy...

Comment: [You mean _array_ constructor, rather than _structure_ constructor.]  Hmm, I hadn't thought that far ahead, about that particular part, I admit.  My main concern was trying to make as little change as possible, but I think you're right: if going for re-writing with an "initialization" subrtoutine (with assignment) then that's a large enough change for us to not worry about that other stuff.

Comment: Many thanks for your competent answers! I fully agree, since I have to rewrite, I do not have to stick to strict F77 rules, at least in my project context. However, I will keep changes to a minimum because I might have to explain to non-programming people that I have not changed the logic of the original source at all. And for this it helps to recognize most of the legacy code in my rework.

Answer (score 0):

One may construct a routine that will be called just once.
The routine will read the data for the matrix from a prepared file.
That will certainly solve your problem with any compiler.